# Let $K/F$ be a finite extension of finite fields and suppose $K=F[\alpha]$ with $\alpha^{15}=1$ then $\mid K:F \mid \leq 4$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Let $K/F$ be a finite extension of finite fields and suppose $K=F[\alpha]$. If $\alpha^{15}=1$ then show that $\mid K:F \mid \leq 4$.

Let $F=\mathbb F_q$, where $q$ is power of some prime $p$, say, and let $\mid K:F\mid=d$, so that $K=\mathbb F_{q^d}$. If $\min_{\alpha,F}(x)=f(x)$, then we have $\deg(f)=d$ and $f(x)\mid(x^{15}-1)$, hence $f(x)\mid (x^{16}-x)$. I wanted to use the fact that $g(x)$ monic irreducible in $\mathbb F_q[x]$. Then $g(x)\mid (x^{q^{n}}-x) \iff \deg(g)\mid n$. But how do I show that characteristic of the field $F$ is $2$. I need help. Thanks.

Comment: I can see how the extension has degree $\leq 8$ since over the integers $X^{15}-1=\Phi_{15}\Phi_{5}\Phi_{3}\Phi_{1}$ which are of degrees $8,4,2,1$ respectively and irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$. So I guess the question is whether $\Phi_{15}$ (which is of degree $8$) can always be split further over a finite field ... I don't know why that should be true, it would surprise me if that were the case (but I'm also not very knowledgeable about splitting behavior).

Comment: If you search for "Cyclotomic Polynomials - Dartmouth College" on Google you will come across slides by Carl Pomerance. On page 3 of the slides it is proven that if $(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^\times$ isn't cyclic then $\Phi_n$ is always reducible mod $p$. Thus $\Phi_{15}$ is reducible mod $p$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: Theorem 49 from **An introduction to the theory of finite fields** by Michel Waldschmidt (to be found online) implies that for $p\neq 3,5$, $\Phi_{15}$ factors as either $2$ polynomials of degree $4$, $4$ polynomials of degree $2$ or $8$ linear polynomials, thus proving the claim for $p\neq 3, 5$. It thus remains to produce the factorizations of $\Phi_{15}$ mod $3$ and $5$ to finish problem.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha yields $\Phi_{15}=(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)^2$ mod $3$ and $\Phi_{15}=(X^2+X+1)^4$ mod $5$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+15th+cyclotomic+polynomial+mod+3 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+15th+cyclotomic+polynomial+mod+5 Note that these factorizations can only improve as one passes from $p$ to a power of $p$.

Comment: Along the lines of order of a polynomial over a finite field we can say that $f(x)\mid x^e-1$, where $e=\gcd(15,q^d-1)$. It is enough to show that $e \leq 4$ for any prime $q$. For $d \leq 4$, this holds trivially.

Comment: Quite. $\Bbb{Z}_{15}^*\simeq\Bbb{Z}_5^*\times \Bbb{Z}_3^*$ (Chinese Remainder Theorem) has exponent four, which is what we need here. It may well be that $\alpha$ has order $3$ or $5$, but that does not change the scene.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Can you kindly explain your comment? Here $\alpha$ satisfy $x^{15}-1$ over $F$. But how do you get $\mathbb Z_{15}^{*}$?

Comment: The conjugates of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{F}_q$ are $\alpha^{q^i}$, $i=0,1,\ldots$. The question is about how many of those are distinct. Or, the lowest positive integer $m$ such that $\alpha^{q^m}=\alpha$. If $\alpha$ has order fifteen, then this number is the order of $q$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{15}^*$, when CRT tells you that $m$ is a factor of $4$. If the order of $\alpha$ is $1,3$ or $5$ it's even simpler. We always get $m\mid 4$.

Comment: Observe that if $\gcd(q,15)>1$ we can immediately cancel the gcd as a factor. This is because there are no roots of unity of order $p$ in any extension $\Bbb{F}_p$, $p$ a prime.

Comment: Thank you very much @JyrkiLahtonen. This approach is really what i was looking for.

Comment: BTW: upon reflection there is absolutely no need to invoke wolfram to get the factorizations of $\Phi_{15}$ mod $3$ and $5$: modulo $3$ we have $X^{15}-1=(X^5-1)^3=(X-1)^3(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)^3$ and similarly $X^{15}-1=(X-1)^5(X^2+X+1)^5$. Thus $\alpha$ has degree $\leq 4$ over a field of characteristic $3$ and degree $\leq 2$ over a field of characteristic $5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$If $K$ is a field with an element $\alpha$ and a subfield $F$ such that

- $F$ is a finite field.$\\[4pt]$

  $K=F(\alpha)$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\alpha^{15}=1$.

then $[K:F]\le 4$.

**Proof:**

For the subfield $F(\alpha^3,\alpha^5)$ of $K$, we have

\begin{align*}
&
\frac{\alpha^5}{\alpha^3}\in F(\alpha^3,\alpha^5)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\alpha^2\in F(\alpha^3,\alpha^5)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^2}\in F(\alpha^3,\alpha^5)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\alpha\in F(\alpha^3,\alpha^5)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $F(\alpha^3,\alpha^5)=F(\alpha)=K$.

Next consider $4$ cases . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;\alpha^3,\alpha^5\in F$.

Then $K=F$, hence $[K:F]=1$.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;\alpha^3\in F,\alpha^5\not\in F$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
\alpha^{15}-1=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(\alpha^5-1)(\alpha^{10}+\alpha^5+1)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\alpha^{10}+\alpha^5+1=0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $\alpha^5$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$, hence $[K:F]=[F(\alpha^5):F]\le 2$.

**Case $(3)$:**$\;\alpha^5\in F,\alpha^3\not\in F$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
\alpha^{15}-1=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(\alpha^3-1)(\alpha^{12}+\alpha^9+\alpha^6+\alpha^3+1)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\alpha^{12}+\alpha^9+\alpha^6+\alpha^3+1=0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $\alpha^3$ is a root of $x^4+x^3+x^2+1$, hence $[K:F]=[F(\alpha^3):F]\le 4$.

**Case $(4)$:**$\;\alpha^3,\alpha^5\not\in F$.

Then the order, $o(\alpha)$, of $\alpha$ in $K^*$ is $15$.

Hence $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,...\alpha^{14}$ are all distinct.

As was shown in case $(2)$, $\alpha^5$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$, hence $[F(\alpha^5):F]\le 2$.

As was shown in case $(3)$, $\alpha^3$ is a root of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

Moreover, $\alpha^6,\alpha^9,\alpha^{12}$ are also roots of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

Since $\alpha^3\not\in F$, it follows that

- $\alpha^{6},\alpha^{9}\not\in F$, else $\alpha^{18}\in F$, contradiction, since $\alpha^{18}=\alpha^{3}$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\alpha^{12}\not\in F$ since $\alpha^{12}=\alpha^{-3}$.

Thus $\alpha^3,\alpha^6,\alpha^9,\alpha^{12}$ are distinct roots of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, and none of them are in $F$.

It follows that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is either irreducible in $F[x]$, or else factors in $F[x]$ as a product of two irreducible quadratics.

Hence $[F(\alpha^3):F]$ equals $2$ or $4$.

Either way, since $[F(\alpha^5):F]\le 2$, it follows that $F(\alpha^5)\subseteq F(\alpha^3)$.

The above line is the only place where we use the hypothesis that $F$ is a finite field.

Hence $K=F(\alpha^3,\alpha^5)=F(\alpha^3)$, so $[K:F]=[F(\alpha^3):F]\le 4$.

Thus in all $4$ cases, we have  $[K:F]\le 4$, as was to be shown.

**Note:**

With some minor adjustments to the above argument (a future edit), we can obtain the slightly stronger result: $[K:F]\in\{1,2,4\}$.